# node-powershell .invoke() not giving a response

Tags: node.js, powershell

I have been using node-powershell for a while fine. When ran locally on windows it still works perfectly but on my Linux server out of nowhere it stopped working and it said WSMan needed to be installed.

After installing WSMan I have run into a lot of issues the current one being that after calling ps.invoke() a few times it suddenly stops doing anything. I am being sure to use the ps.clear() function to clear old commands.
nothing is even triggered with it in a try catch. Any idea if there is something new to be done?

My powershell is setup as so:
Shell = require('node-powershell');
const ps = new Shell({
executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
noProfile: true,
pwsh: true
});

Comment: "when I call my ps.invoke()" - what commands did you attach to `ps` (presumably an instance of [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell))?

Comment: Yes:
const Shell = require('node-powershell');
const ps = new Shell({
        executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
        noProfile: true,
        pwsh: true
    });

Comment: Something i forgot to mention is that it does actually run the command but after invoking 4 times it seems to stop working. I am using ps.clear() between invoking too.

Comment: Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73908017/edit) with these pertinent details :)